# ¿Cómo cambiar color input number en array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, color, input

Estoy intentando resolver el siguiente ejercicio:

- Crear web con un input de tipo numérico que pida notas y dos botones “Añadir” y “Mostrar”.
- Al pulsar "añadir" se añadirá el contenido a un array vacío previamente creado.
- Al pulsar "mostrar" se mostrarán las notas, una por línea. Las inferiores a 5 en color rojo y las iguales/superiores a 5 en color verde.

Con el código que adjunto, me saca si el valor que introduzco es menor a 5 - true en color rojo. Si es igual o mayor - true en color verde.

No me saca los valores en sí (4.1 o 5,2, por ejemplo). Ni me los lista, sólo aparece un true en un color o en otro.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

```
<body>

    <form name="cuarto" method="post">
        <label for="notas">Escribe un texto:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="notas" name="notas" placeholder="¿NOTA?" min="0" max="10" step=".01"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="añadir()">AÑADIR</button>

        <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">MOSTRAR</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

    </form>

    <script>

        var arraynotas = [];


        function añadir(){
            let nota = document.getElementById('notas').value.split(" ");
            arraynotas = arraynotas.concat(nota);
            document.getElementById('notas').value = "";
            } 

        function mostrar(){
            if (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arraynotas.join("<br>")<5) {
                document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
            } else if (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arraynotas.join("<br>")>=5) {
                document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "green";
            } 

        }


    </script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arraynotas.join("<br>")<5){}`

Tienes que entender que cuando se ejecuta el `if` de arriba ocurren 2 cosas:

1. Primero se evalua la expresión `arraynotas.join("<br>") < 5` si esta expresión se cumple su valor (`true` o `false`) se asignará a `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML`.
2. Luego de asignar dicho valor al elemento `demo` se evalua la condición `if` que quedaría así `if(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML)` y esta condición será cierta o falsa dependiendo del valor que se ha asigando previamente.

Por eso el contenido de `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` es `true` o `false` debido a la asignación que se hace luego de evaluar `arraynotas.join("<br>") < 5`.

Para listar todas las notas tienes que recorrer el `arraynotas` y crear el html para insertarlo en elemento `demo`. Puedes usar el metodo `map` para generar los elementos y concatenarlos con `join`.

```js
 var arraynotas = [];


 function añadir() {
   let nota = document.getElementById('notas').value.split(" ");
   arraynotas = arraynotas.concat(nota);
   document.getElementById('notas').value = "";
 }

 function mostrar() {
   const html = arraynotas.map((nota) => 
     `<span style="color: ${nota >= 5 ? 'green' : 'red'}">${nota}</span><br>`
   ).join('');
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;

 }
```

```html
<form name="cuarto" method="post">
        <label for="notas">Escribe un texto:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="notas" name="notas" placeholder="¿NOTA?" min="0" max="10" step=".01"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="añadir()">AÑADIR</button>

        <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">MOSTRAR</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

    </form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Se podría hacer utilizando...? document.getElementById("formato").style.color="red"

Comment: de nada. No entiendo tu duda. Pero si tienes un elemento en DOM(html) que tenga por `id="formato"` puedes cambiar los estilos.